# Nested classes in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, yii

Recently, I came across a situation where I need to use nested classes in my code.

Actually, I have implemented Threading in php,  I am using worker and concept of pooling in threads.

I have developed the application in YII framework, threads basically perform some computation and I need to save that computation into the database.

I cannot access the YII framework model files in the thread class since the thread class doesn't know anything about the YII framework. If I somehow make the MyCustomThread class as the nested classes within YII, that will be the property of YII super class and all the operations can be done easily.

I looked into the concept of namespace but it didn't work probably my child class extend the THREADED class which causes the problem.

Your thoughts please??

Comment: How did you imeplement "Threading"?

Comment: Using pthreads library in php.